# Unexpected result from face-font-rescale-alist in emacs

Tags: emacs

I am trying to modify the default size of a font using

```
(add-to-list 'face-font-rescale-alist (cons "^.*STIXGeneral.*$" 0.95) t)
```

This is supposed to rescale all fonts with name STIXGeneral by 0.95, because for me that font is a little taller than the standard font. The resulting value of `face-font-rescale-alist` is:

```
(("-cdac$" . 1.3) ("^.*STIXGeneral.*$" . 0.95))
```

However, with emacs 24.3 (also the git version, and also pre-release 24.3.92.1), the result of adding the above to `.emacs` is that the font is wrong on every frame apart from the initial frame. Running 24.3 with `-Q --eval="<expression above>"` gives:

```
(message "%s" (face-all-attributes 'default (selected-frame)))
New frame: ((:family . Geneva) (:foundry . apple) (:width . normal) (:height . 120) (:weight . normal) (:slant . normal) (:underline) (:overline) (:strike-through) (:box) (:inverse-video) (:foreground . Black) (:background . White) (:stipple) (:inherit))
Initial frame: ((:family . Menlo) (:foundry . apple) (:width . normal) (:height . 120) (:weight . normal) (:slant . normal) (:underline) (:overline) (:strike-through) (:box) (:inverse-video) (:foreground . Black) (:background . White) (:stipple) (:inherit))
```

With my regular `.emacs` on git version:

```
New frame: "((:family . Helvetica) (:foundry . nil) (:width . normal) (:height . 110) (:weight . normal) (:slant . normal) (:underline) (:overline) (:strike-through) (:box) (:inverse-video) (:foreground . #000000) (:background . AliceBlue) (:stipple) (:inherit))"
Initial frame: ((:family . Source Code Pro) (:foundry . nil) (:width . normal) (:height . 110) (:weight . normal) (:slant . normal) (:underline) (:overline) (:strike-through) (:box) (:inverse-video) (:foreground . #000000) (:background . AliceBlue) (:stipple) (:inherit))
```

The face in the initial frame is the one I expect. The place where `face-font-rescale-alist` influences the font is in `font_score` in `font.c` ([link](https://github.com/mirrors/emacs/blob/master/src/font.c#L2162)). The same problem occurs in git version if I replace `(add-to-list ...)` with `(setq face-font-rescale-alist nil)`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm. In `startup.el` the following code detects changes in `face-font-rescale-alist`, and resets the default font, while also ignoring changes coming from `custom-set-face` (which is how I was setting the font with the customization interface):

```
;; startup.el:670
(unless (eq face-font-rescale-alist old-face-font-rescale-alist)
 (set-face-attribute 'default nil :font (font-spec)))
```

It is therefore necessary to set `face-font-rescale-alist` after the code that tries to erase customizations. This can be done by attaching advice to `frame-notice-user-settings`, which runs after the face-resetting code:

```
;; in .emacs
(defadvice frame-notice-user-settings (before my:rescale-alist)
  (message "Set face-font-rescale-alist")
  (add-to-list 'face-font-rescale-alist
               (cons (font-spec :family "STIXGeneral") 0.95) t))
(ad-activate 'frame-notice-user-settings)
```

This applies `face-font-rescale-alist` as I would have expected it to work from reading documentation.